# Use of @class with custom class on MVC Html.ActionLink with HtmlAttributes failing

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

I've read through the links here I could find about these techs.  No exact match I could see, so...

I have a custom CSS class, I'm trying to apply it using an `HtmlAttributes` containing `@class`, but it never overwrites the underlying CSS (in the same file) for an `<a>`.  Even deleting the default CSS for `a` fails.  By contrast, when I use `@style` in `HtmlAttributes`, it works.

I'm assuming there's a subtle but boneheaded mistake in my syntax.

NB: My goal is to make the links look like buttons.  For now I'll settle for removing underlining as proof of concept.

Here is the Razor markup that *works*, where `quote` is an object that contains text in a property, and whose ID is used against the model / db:

```
@Html.ActionLink(quote.QuoteContent.SupplyBytesAsString(), "ReadQuote",
new {quoteContentID = quote.QuoteContentID }, 
new { @style = "text-decoration: none;" })
```

Fine.  This dumps underlining.  But the following *doesn't* work, and I can't tell why.  The actual CSS comes last here.  It dumps underlining among other things, none of which get applied.

```
@Html.ActionLink(quote.QuoteContent.SupplyBytesAsString(), "ReadQuote",
new { quoteContentID = quote.QuoteContentID },
new { @class = "quote" })
```

This is my CSS right now, just the relevant sections (?), Microsoft's default  and mine.  I've tried every single option that various sources recommended for my `quotes` class... `.quote` then `a`, `a .quote`, `.quote` by itself, colons, anything else I could find or dream up.  Maybe I missed something, ugh.

Anyway, I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong before my head explodes.  Thanks...

```
a
{
color: #333;
outline: none;
padding-left: 3px;
padding-right: 3px;
text-decoration: underline;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover
{
color: #333;
}

a:hover
{
background-color: #c7d1d6;
}


a.quote
{
border: 1px inset #808080;
color: #333;
outline: none;
padding-left: 3px;
padding-right: 3px;
text-decoration: none;
}

a.quote:active, a.quote:hover
{
background-color: #FFFF66;
}


a.quote:link, a.quote:visited
{
color: #333;
background-color: #00CC66;
}
```

< end of question >

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NDpRCy)

Comment: How you attache your css? Probably, your css didn't attache to your html.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought of that briefly but thought, "that can't be it."  I didn't refer to the CSS anywhere in my View, but it's one that was auto-generated and I've edited it.  I'll start looking there.  Hope that's all it is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **idlerboris** for their comment.  I checked out the issue they suggested (including viewing source markup from the browser) and the CSS *was* attaching.

So, it turns out I did make a boneheaded mistake as I feared, and long before the point where I posted here.

In short, the CSS doesn't work because I don't have `.quote` defined by itself in my CSS file.  Naturally, I started with `.quote` defined standalone, but an error somewhere at that time (probably over in Razor) must have confused me and I got into hasty fixing instead of doing it right.

***If*** there's a syntax lesson here, it's this obvious one: Don't try to use a style in combo-selector CSS syntax unless it's already defined by itself.

Another pointer: Don't forget to refresh in the browser when you debug and you haven't edited your page content.  Caching will vex you.  Not the root problem here, but forgetting caching didn't help.

The ***main*** lesson here is clearly: Code slowly, prefer looking things up over guessing, and no matter what, only change **one** variable in each experiment!  ***sigh***